# Tabular - make some border lines invisible

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am trying to make the highlighted lines of the table invisible. How would you achieve this?

Many thanks

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\textbf{2}\quad Table
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
 & \textbf{Dan} & \textbf{Liz}\\ \hline
\text{B} & 61 kg & 68 kg\\ \hline
\text{C} & 72 kg & 68 kg\\ \hline
\text{D} & 65 kg & 70 kg\\ \hline
\text{E} & 70 kg & 63 kg\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Too bad you haven't made a more intensive use of the yellow marker. This table would look better with only 3 lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple: remove the `|` on the very left, and replace `\hline` by `\cline{2-3}`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\textbf{2}\quad Table
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|}
\cline{2-3}
 & \textbf{Dan} & \textbf{Liz}\\ \cline{2-3}
\text{B} & 61 kg & 68 kg\\ \cline{2-3}
\text{C} & 72 kg & 68 kg\\ \cline{2-3}
\text{D} & 65 kg & 70 kg\\ \cline{2-3}
\text{E} & 70 kg & 63 kg\\ \cline{2-3}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]